# Finding objects that are not associated in has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I have simple classes like these:

```
class Book
  has_many :book_categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :book_categorizations, source: :book_category
end

class BookCategorizations
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :book_category
end

class BookCategory
  has_many :book_categorizations
  has_many :books, through: :book_categorizations
end
```

I would like to find `Book`s that have no category. How can I query that using `where`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `scope` with an `LEFT JOIN` to your model:

```
# in book.rb
scope :without_categories, lambda {
  joins('LEFT JOIN book_categorizations ON books.id = book_categorizations.book_id').
    where(book_categorizations: { book_category_id: nil })
}
```

Which could be used like:

```
Book.without_categories
#=> returns books without a category
```

---

How it works:

Imaging you have a `fruits` and a `colors` table:

```
fruits
id | name
 1 | Apple
 2 | Orange
 3 | Banana

colors
id | name
 1 | black
 2 | red
 3 | yellow
```

And a `colors_fruits` join table:

```
colors_fruits
color_id | fruit_id
2        | 1           # red Apple
3        | 3           # yellow Banana
```

Since Rails' `joins` method generates [`INNER JOIN`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables), all joins would only return fruits that have at least one color. The orange wouldn't be in the list, because it does not have a color (therefore no join is possible):

```
Fruit.joins(:colors)
#=> red Apple, yellow Banana (simplified)
```

But when we are interested into fruits that do not have an color, then we need an `LEFT JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` includes all elements from the left table - even if there is not matching on the right table (unfortunately there is no Rails helper for this kind of joins):

```
Fruits.joins('LEFT JOIN colors_fruits ON colors_fruits.fruits_id = fruits.id')
```

This generates a result like:

```
id | color  | fruit_id | color_id
 1 | Apple  | NULL     | NULL
 2 | Orange | 2        | 1
 3 | Banana | 3        | 3
```

Now we just need to exclude the ones that do not have a `color_id`

```
Fruits.joins('LEFT JOIN colors_fruits ON colors_fruits.fruits_id = fruits.id').
       where(colors_fruits: { color_id: nil })
```

You might want to read about the different types of [`SQL JOINS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). And there is this well known [diagram about joins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png).

Comment: The `book_categories` table doesn't have a `book_id` column. I'm using a join table, `book_categorizations`. This wouldn't work, but I'll try converting this to what I need.

Comment: @hattenn : I updated my answer and added a short explaination.